# Django URL Pattern not triggered

Tags: django, django-1.9

I am trying to implement an approve and decline functionality of a profile using the following approach:

```
/user/area/decline/234322 
/user/area/approve/234322
```

So I wrote the following URL pattern:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^user/area/decline/(?P<userid>\[0-9]+)/$', views.DeclineUser),
    url(r'^user/area/approve/(?P<userid>\[0-9]+)/$', views.ApproveUser),
    url(r'^user/area/$', views.Index),
    .
    .)
```

And my views:

```
@login_required
def DeclineUser(request, userid=""):
    print("Here: " + userid)

@login_required
def ApproveUser(request, userid=""):
    print("Here: " + userid)
```

But something is wrong and the methods are not triggered and the Index is triggered instead so I guess the problem is that the URL RegEx is not matching what I need.

Comment: Any errors? What *does* happen?

Comment: As I said the method is not triggered and the closer match is triggered instead which is `user/area`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your url's have a `\` in them so you are escaping the opening `[` bracket, you just need to remove those slashes.

```
url(r'^user/area/decline/(?P<userid>[0-9]+)/$', views.DeclineUser),
url(r'^user/area/approve/(?P<userid>[0-9]+)/$', views.ApproveUser),
```

Comment: Correct but this didn't fixed the problem. The /user/area is triggered instead.

Comment: Well now I get the following error: `DeclineUser got an unexpected keyword argument 'userid'`

Comment: @John - Thats a different issue to do with your view, the views you've shown have different names